# Calculate the value of $e$ from integral definition

Tags: definite-integrals, logarithms

Starting with the definition of $e$ as $$\int_1^e \frac{dx}{x} = 1,$$ how can I show that $e = 2.718\ldots$?

Comment: $$\int \frac{1}{x}dx=\ln x+C$$

Comment: @RedMushroom Sure, but from $\ln e=1$, how do you get $e= 2.718\ldots$?

Comment: I think you can show that $2<e<3$ starting from that.

Comment: Consider the function $\displaystyle F(x)=\int_1^x \dfrac{1}{t}dt-1$ and use the intermediate value theorem. The problem is to evaluate the integral. Riemann's sums can help. x->1/x is a decreasing function for x>1

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**. An elementary approach. One may consider
$$
I_0=1-\frac1{e}, \quad I_n=\int_{\large\frac1{e}}^1\left(-\ln x \right)^n\:dx, \quad n\ge1,
$$ then integrating by parts,
$$
\begin{align}
I_n&=\left[ x \frac{}{}\left(-\ln x \right)^n\right]_{\large\frac1{e}}^1 +n\int_{\large\frac1{e}}^1\left(-\ln x \right)^{n-1}\:dx
\\&=-\frac1{e}+nI_{n-1}
\end{align}
$$ dividing by $n!$ gives
$$
\frac{I_n}{n!}-\frac{I_{n-1}}{(n-1)!}=-\frac1{e}\cdot \frac1{n!},\qquad n\ge1,
$$ by summing, terms telescope to get
$$
e=1+\frac1{1!}+\cdots+\frac1{n!}+\frac1{n!}\int_{\large\frac1{e}}^1\left(-\ln x \right)^n\:dx,
$$ then one may observe that
$$
0<\int_{\large\frac1{e}}^1\left(-\ln x \right)^n\:dx< 2
$$ giving, for $n=1,2,\cdots$,

> $$
> 1+\frac1{1!}+\cdots+\frac1{n!}<e<1+\frac1{1!}+\cdots+\frac1{n!}+\frac2{n!}
> $$

which may be useful for a numerical approximation of $e$.

Comment: I think there is some error here, maybe the last $n+2$ should have no factorial?

Comment: The point being that $e$ is *not* less than $\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{1}{i!} + \frac{1}{(n+2)!}$.

Comment: @Ian I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Comment: Looks good now.

Comment: @Ian In fact we have $e<1+\frac1{1!}+\cdots+\frac1{n!}+\frac1{(n+1)n!}$. But I try not to use all properties of $e^{x}$... Thanks.

Comment: No, that's not right either. That's just the next term of the sum. You do have, for example, that result with the last numerator replaced by $e$. That's the estimate I used in my answer.

Comment: Oops, I meant $e<1+\frac1{1!}+\cdots+\frac1{n!}+\frac1{(n+1)(n+1)!}$ (I'm at work  busy, I shouldn't be on MSE, writing errors...)

Answer (score 1):

Though it is a bit roundabout, you can define $\ln(x)=\int_1^x \frac{1}{t} dt$ and $\exp$ to be the inverse of $\ln$. It then follows that $\exp(1)$ is your $e$. You can now develop the Taylor series of $\exp$. From this development you find $e=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}$ and also

$$0<e-\sum_{n=0}^N \frac{1}{n!}<\frac{e}{(N+1)!}.$$

This follows from the Lagrange error formula and a little bit of estimation. Hence we have

$$\sum_{n=0}^N \frac{1}{n!}<e<\frac{(N+1)!}{(N+1)!-1} \sum_{n=0}^N \frac{1}{n!}.$$

You wanted to infer the first four digits, which can be done with $N=6$: rounding the lower bound down to five digits and the upper bound up to five digits, you get $2.7180<e<2.7186$.

You can also attempt to directly manipulate the integral numerically; for example, for any $b \geq 1$ and positive integer $N$, you have

$$\sum_{i=1}^N \frac{1}{1+\frac{b-1}{N} i} \frac{b-1}{N} \leq \int_1^b \frac{1}{x} dx \leq \sum_{i=0}^{N-1} \frac{1}{1+\frac{b-1}{N} i} \frac{b-1}{N}.$$

So to prove that $e>b$, it is enough to prove that for some $N$, $\sum_{i=0}^{N-1} \frac{1}{1+\frac{b-1}{N} i} \frac{b-1}{N}<1$. Similarly to prove $e<b$ it is enough to prove that for some $N$, $\sum_{i=1}^N \frac{1}{1+\frac{b-1}{N} i} \frac{b-1}{N}>1$. This will be much more computationally expensive than the previous approach, however.